# WinUI3 Xaml align column grid to the right

Tags: xaml, winui-3

This is the XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <MenuBar  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" RequestedTheme="Dark" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="TopMenu" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  >
        <FontIcon  x:Name="btnDark" Glyph="&#xE790;" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <FontIcon  x:Name="btnSettings" Glyph="&#xE713;" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And I got this one:
[image]

Note that the menu is dynamically created, it's not in the XAML. How can I create the two font icons at the far right ?

Like, for example, Notepad:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This will let the first column, the `MenuBar`, take the minimum required width, and let the second column, the `StackPanel` with `FontIcon`s take the rest.

In your case you want the oposite, so:

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: That is weird. I actually created a sample app with your XAML and both ``FonIcon``s are aligned to the right.

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?